# How do I make sure the content inside a div does not get cut off by sticky element attached to the bottom of the div?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a wrapper that is essentially a view more container. I have instructions to make sure the content does not get cut off by the "view more" div that is attached to the bottom of the wrapper.

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem in order to make sure the content is not cut off. 
This is the default wrapper. You can see how the children start getting cut off:

[image: a busy cat]

This is the expanded wrapper. It is still getting cut off, so I know I am having some css issues:

[image: a busy cat]

the general wrapper structure in React is like:

```
<FieldWrapperStyle>
  <div>
    {this.props.children}
    <ExpandBtn /> //this is a span
  </div>
</FieldWrapperStyle>
```

Here is the Wrapper in a styled component:

```
export const FieldWrapperStyle = styled(Row)`
    position: relative;
    height: calc((100vh - 255px) / 4);
    .col-md-6 {
      max-width: 100%;
      flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
    .field-body {
      transition-timing-function: ease-in;
      background: #fff;
      height: inherit;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 1rem !important;
      z-index: 0;
      width: 100%;
        &.expand {
        box-shadow: 0 10px 30px #999;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        min-height: 400px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
            &.expBottom {
                bottom: 0px;
                //top: auto;
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Here is the ExpandBtn span that goes inside to the bottom:

```
export const ExpandBtn = styled.span`
    background: none;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 15px 15px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-image: linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,100%,.5),hsla(0,0%,100%,.6),#fff,#fff,#fff);
    z-index: 780;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    &:after {
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 7px 5px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 0;
      margin: 6px 5px;
      width: 0;
    }
`;
```

Any ideas would be super helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `overflow: hidden` property from `FieldWrapperStyle`.

The overflow property specifies what should happen if content overflows an element's box. When it is set to `hidden` the content is clipped.

Comment: This won't work because the rest of the content overflows out of the div box.

Comment: This put me on the right path. Thanks @gergana